# Java beginner here data type short

Tags: java

Hi i just have a question regarding the data type short with implicit conversion.

It says here that `short n = 99999;` would be equal to a value of -31073. Why is it equal to that number? The minimum number possible for a short is  -32,768 and max of 32,767 (inclusive). Also, I don't understand why this is negative?

Comment: `short n = 99999;` would not compile... show your code to better illustrate your description.

Comment: _It says here that short n = 99999_ It says where, exactly? That does not compile.

Comment: oh no. This is just an exercise I am trying to answer. There's no code fragment involved. The -31073 is the solution btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer value `99999`, in binary form is:

```
1 1000 0110 1001 1111
```

and as you can see it needs more the **15 binary digits** (**+1** for reserved for the +/- sign) 
that a value of type `short` can store.  
So when you *"squeeze"* this value inside a **16 bits** space, you get the last 16 binary digits:

```
1000 0110 1001 1111
```

and this equals to the `short` value of `-31073`.

Comment: Thank you!! I totally forgot that short is a 16 bit signed twos complement integer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Primitive type like `int`, `short`, etc. in Java are signed, except `char`.
2. `short` in Java is 16-bit signed integer.

[JLS 11 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/jls11.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4550%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C449%2Cnull%5D) [JLS 8 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4442%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C449%2Cnull%5D)

Then, for a `short` integer `32767`, the internal binary is like:

```
01111111 11111111
```

When we plus 1 on this number, we get this binary:

```
10000000 00000000
```

which is `-32768` if we read it as **signed short**.

Then we can get this mapping:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
...
32766 -> 32766
32767 -> 32767
32768 -> -32768 // This is called "overflow"
32769 -> -32767
...
65534 -> -2
65535 -> -1
65536 -> 0
65537 -> 1
... // loop
```

As for "short" 99999, it can be reduced as 34463 first (= 99999 % 65536), then due to this mapping, any number between 32768 and 65535 should be subtracted from 65536, then 34463 is mapped into the final result `-31073`.